# How can I automate the "Apply to enclosed itmes.." dialogue to reassert folder permissions on a Mac?

Tags: macos, permissions

I'm running a Mojave file server that regularly needs this file & folder permissions fix. Since I have 10+ different shares I'd like to automate the "fixing" to run every 24 hours using something like "script Editor" or "Automator". Some users are ready only, other are read/write, this needs to be maintained. Anybody have any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you have  a few ideas. Have you tried them yet? What have you tried?

Comment: Instead of automating the Finder, do this from the shell (the command line in Terminal).